# How can I get the ABI of a smart contract on the Ethereum blockchain and use it to decode transactions and logs?

Tags: transactions, abi, raw-transaction

If I have the address of a smart contract and I want to fetch its ABI, to decode transactions and logs.

I know one way is to use Etherscan, but I want to do this operation in bulk, and Etherscan’s limit of 100000 queries/day is gonna be a challenge for me, so that’s my last resort.

Can anyone help me out with any dataset or any resources where I can get all (publicly available) the ABIs.

Answer (score 0):

Hey if the Smart contract is verified you can the ABI of the Smart Contract from there.

If you get the ABI of the Contract you can use web3.js to decode the logs of the Contract

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I know that we can get the ABI from etherscan, and then decode it. But I wanna know how to get the ABI without depending on etherscan.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This May or Maynot work for all Contract. But The Bytecode of the Smart Contract has Meta data in it.

And That Meta data has IPFS Hash and Solc Version in Which the code has been  complied.

Here You can get details of smart contract like abi, bytecode, smart contract, opcode.


And You can use web3.eth.getCode(contractAddress) to get the Bytecode